# Missing dependency packages while installing Viber

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, dependencies, 19.04, viber

As the title says, some packages which are required by Viber is missing. I am quite noob to Ubuntu. Can anyone guide me. Thanks

```
Selecting previously unselected package viber.
(Reading database ... 183037 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack viber.deb ...
Unpacking viber (10.3.0.37) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of viber:
 viber depends on libssl1.0.0; however:
  Package libssl1.0.0 is not installed.
 viber depends on gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly; however:
  Package gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly is not installed.
 viber depends on gstreamer1.0-libav; however:
  Package gstreamer1.0-libav is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package viber (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 viber
```

Comment: Indicate Ubuntu version you are using. Not clear how you attempt installing Viber, because it likely is not in the default software sources for any version.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04... I tried installing using dpkg command

Comment: Try `sudo apt install ./viber.deb`; it will automatically install all dependencies if they are available.

Comment: Got this error now ... 

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 viber : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: It means you are on 19.04, but the package you are trying to install is not compatible wth it (it requires `libssl1.0.0`, which is not available). You can try to contact the developers of the package to let them know about this issue, or just install 18.04 instead.

Comment: Hello, @thenewbie, please review my updated [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155232/566421).

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, as [@fkraiem](https://askubuntu.com/users/256317/fkraiem) describes within the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155224/missing-dependency-packages-while-installing-viber/1155232#comment1921653_1155224), the package `libssl1.0.0` is missing in the **Ubuntu 19.04**'s repository. Probably this should be reported as bug to Ubuntu's team. Fortunately, the good news is: you can download and install this package from 18.10's repository.

Go to the [download page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libssl1.0.0/download) and click on the link `security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` (located on the middle of the page), then an installation dialogue will be started. After that you can install Viber.

All together from the CLI:

```bsh
sudo apt update

# download and install the dependencies
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb 

# download and install Viber
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
sudo apt install ./viber.deb

# just in case
sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

---

The original answer, that is proofed for **Ubuntu 16.04 - 18.04**:

The the last few times when I was installing Viber, I needed to install some dependencies manually by the option `--fix-broken` packages of `apt`... I just tried to install Viber on fresh Ubuntu 18.04 and encountered an [error](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dNQR63WFZw/), but it is different from yours. The mentioned approach solved the problem again. Here it is:

```
sudo apt update
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: This will **not** work on 19.04, which is what OP is using.

Comment: Also, `dpkg -i` is now basically obsolete; local DEBs can be installed with `apt install`.

Comment: Worked fine on 19.10 eoan, just installed libssl1.0.0 next to the existing libssl1.1. Thanks!